# Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function on a region $\Omega$ that vanishes on a sequence of distinct points with a limit point , then $f=0$ .

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reviewing Stein's complex analysis , and there's one theorem I listed follows:

> Suppose $ f$ is a holomorphic function on a region $\Omega$ that vanishes on a sequence of distinct points with a limit point in $\Omega$ , then $f$ is identically $0$ . (Here region means both open and connect)

My question is : If we do not assume the limit point is in $\Omega$ , the limit point might in the boundary of $\Omega$ , can we get the similar conclusion ? Since the [orginal proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2350148/accumulation-points-of-a-holomorphic-function) using the power series of the limit point $z_0$ , I have no idea how to deal with this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if the limit point is outside the domain then we cannot conclude that the function is identically zero.

To be specific, the [Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product) gives a very specific construction of functions with prescribed zeros within the unit disk (potentially infinitely many!) which are not identically zero. The zeros do need to satisfy some growth conditions, though - they have to be moving towards the boundary of the disk quickly enough.

Comment: I see it ! Thanks for the answer .

Answer (score 2):

No, take $f(z)=\sin(1/z)$ on the punctured plane. Then $f=0$ on $z_k=\frac 1{k\pi}$ and $z_k\to 0$ but $f$ is not identically 0.